# Set inverse belongsTo with hasMany data

Tags: json, ember.js, ember-data

### Problem statement

I have two models `Chapter` and `Item`. A `Chapter` can have many `Item`s. The models are declared as follows.

```
App.Chapter = DS.Model.extend({
  items: DS.hasMany('item')
});

App.Item = DS.Model.extend({
  chapter: DS.belongsTo('chapter')
});
```

When I make a request for all the chapters, I include the items as well in the response. An example JSON response is as follows.

```
{
  items: [
    { id: 1 },
    { id: 2 },
    { id: 3 }
  ]
  chapters: [
    {
      id: 1,
      items: [1, 2]
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      items: [3]
    }
  ]
}
```

The hasMany relationship on chapters work fine, i.e. if I do `chapter.items` it returns the correct list of items. However, the belongsTo association for an item is not set. For any given item, calling `item.chapter` always returns null.

### My question

How can I set the belongsTo relationship on `Item`s without having to specify a `chapter` property in the JSON response?

### What I've tried

I've tried making the inverse relationship explicit on both ends, but this doesn't solve the problem.

```
App.Chapter = DS.Model.extend({
  items: DS.hasMany('item', { inverse: 'chapter' })
});

App.Item = DS.Model.extend({
  chapter: DS.belongsTo('chapter', { inverse: 'items' })
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: honestly the easiest approach is to adhere to Ember's standards, but I realize you don't always have control of the endpoint.

Okay, with that out of the way, you could set up a custom serializer which modifies the json after you've received it.

See:

Examples of Serializers:
https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md

The normal rest serializer:
https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/serializers/rest_serializer.js

```
App.PostSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
  // This method will be called 3 times: once for the post, and once
  // for each of the comments
  extractArray: function(store, primaryType, payload) {
    // fix up the payload at this point.
  }
});
```

Comment: I understand that it's better to adhere to Ember's standards, but in this case setting the relationship on `Item`s as well would be extremely costly performance-wise on the server. But thanks for your answer! I solved it by explicitly setting the relationship in the `extractArray` method. Much cheaper computation-wise!